# How to change background color of a div after few seconds?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to change the background-color of a div after few seconds. I used **setTimeout** property. But it does not work.

**HTML code**

```
<div [style.background-color]="this.color1 == 'true' ? '#fb8857' : '#ffffff'">
</div>
```

**TS code**

```
color1 = true;

 ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.color1=false;
    },5000);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to compare the `color1` property against a boolean value, like this:

```
<div [style.background-color]="this.color1 === true ? '#fb8857' : '#ffffff'"></div>
```

Or what would be the same:

```
<div [style.background-color]="this.color1 ? '#fb8857' : '#ffffff'"></div>
```

### **[Working Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/change-color-after-timeout)**.

Comment: Thanks.....I used [style.background-color]="this.color1 ? '#fb8857' : '#ffffff'" and its work.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :) @KirandeepKaur

Answer (score 1):

You could define `color1` as the background color:

```
color1: string = '#fb8857';

ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.color1 = '#ffffff';
    }, 5000);
}
```

And set the value directly with data binding (no need to refer to `this` in the template):

```
<div [style.background-color]="color1">
</div>
```

You can see this code at work in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dzk6vz).

Answer (score 0):

**You can easily do it with angular animation like**

```
 export const buttonStateTrigger = trigger('buttonState', [  
        state('valid', style({
            backgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
            borderColor: 'green',
            color: 'green'
          })),
        state('invalid', style({
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            borderColor: 'darkred',
            color: 'white'
          })),
        transition('invalid => valid', [
            group([
                animate(100, style({
                    transform : 'scale(1.1)'
                })),
                animate(200, style({
                    backgroundColor: 'lightgreen'
                })),
                animate(200, style({
                    transform : 'scale(1)'
                })),
            ])
        ]),
        transition('valid => invalid', [
            group([
                animate(100, style({
                    transform : 'scale(1.1)'
                })),
                animate(200, style({
                    backgroundColor: 'red'
                })),
                animate(200, style({
                    transform : 'scale(1)'
                })),
            ])
        ])
    ]);
```

**you need to import desire component like** 

`animations: [
    buttonStateTrigger
  ]`

**HTML** 
`

```
 <button
    type="submit"
    [disabled]="!f.valid"
    [@buttonState]="f.valid ? 'valid' : 'invalid' "
    class="btn btn-success">Create Project</button>
```

`
** Please enable  angular animation  **
you can follow my project https://github.com/ShahinAlKabirMitul/AngularStyling

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quote you used in your div tag 'true'

```
<div [style.background-color]="this.color1 ? '#fb8857' : '#ffffff'"> </div>
```

This will work.